# How to use max and SCSS variables together

Tags: css, sass

I have been struggling trying to use css `max()` and scss variables together. For instance, `font-size: max(5vw, 991px * 0.075);` works, but the following:

```
$lg: 991px * 0.075;
font-size: max(5vw, $lg);
```

or

```
$lg: 991px;
font-size: max(5vw, $b * 0.075);
```

throws  *"Error: Incompatible units px and vw,"* even though it is virtually the same as the former. And the following:

```
$lg: 991px;
$-lg: calc($lg * 0.075);
font-size: max(5vw, $-lg);
```

throws *"Error: calc($b * 0.075) is not a number."*

```
$lg: 991px;
font-size: max(5vw, calc($lg * 0.075));
```

Doesn't throw an error, but gives the wrong results. How can I do this? Why wouldn't `max()` between vw and px work, even though it should work with css natively?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, you just need to use `#{}` to interpolate the variable. I didn't know that as I am new to scss.